# How to catch exceptions in the main that are raised while running PyQt application?

Tags: python, exception, pyqt

Suppose we have this simple main program:

```
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from initial import InitialWindow

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        ex = InitialWindow()
        ex.show()
        app.exec_()
    except:
        # Do something
        print('Hello')
```

The application being run is pretty complex, and there are several windows being created. Doing an exception handler for each class that is working internally is rather tedious, so I was thinking if there is a way to catch *any* exception raised during the execution of `app` in the main, and do something before terminating the program.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own error handler which will capture standard error. For example like this;

```
import sys
import traceback

from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets
from initial import InitialWindow


def error_handler(etype, value, tb):
    error_msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype, value, tb))
    # do something with the error message, for example print it 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.excepthook = error_handler  # redirect std error

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = InitialWindow()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Sorry if this is too basic, but I'm not too used to python exceptions yet. Could you please post how the entire code would be? I mean, could you merge your code with the one I've posted?

Comment: Where is `traceback` defined?

Comment: @Tendero oh right, forgot that you need to import it, fixed. P.S. feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel it answered your question.

Comment: @Tendero also need to import the `sys` module, edited to show that